# Android content provider permissions

Tags: android, permissions, android-contentprovider

I have two questions related to permissions in the `<provider>` element:

1. If `exported` is set to true, does that mean every app can access the provider and the rest of the attributes don't matter? What if `exported` is true and `readPermission` is set? Does an external application still need to have read permission?
2. According to the documentation, `grantUriPermissions` can temporarily overcome restrictions imposed by `readPermission` and `writePermission`. What does 'temporarily' mean in this case? If `grantUriPermissions` is true, does that make `readPermission` and `writePermission` unnecessary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first question.
1.Yes exported means other app can access the provider whereas the permissions is for your app that how to use the provider.

Here is the developers docs url
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ProviderElement